# Can you use a wide range 11-42 cassette with a double crankset

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, drivetrain

Can you use a 10 or 11 speed wide range (11-42, 10-42, or 11-40) cassette with a double crankset?

I know these wide range cassettes are typically built for a 1x setup on a mountain bike, but is there any reason why you couldn't pair this with a front derailleur and run it with a double crankset? I would assume to be running a type 2 clutch rear derailleur anyway to support the wide range and reduce chain slap on smaller cogs.

Answer (score 2):

An 11-42t cassette as per the title, no. An 11-40t however as you mention, yes! [Shimano has the answer here.](http://www.bikeradar.com/mtb/news/article/shimano-deore-xt-m8000-11-speed-first-look-44084/) So if you're not already tied into SRAM then I'd jump ship to Shimano. They have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you may have is chain.  With SRAM you have an 1X chain that will most likely not be compatible with your double chanrings.  You may be able to use a regular 11 speed chain on a wide 1X cassette.  But that is a potential problem.  I would hate to spend big bucks on the cassette to find out.

With SRAM [1X](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/1x) is a total group and not designed to be interchangeable with non 1X.  But some components may turn out to be compatible.

Comment: FWIW the Compatibility Map 2016 MTB Components on SRAM's website indicates that the  XX1 chain should only be used on 1x drivetrains, while listing PC 1130 and PC X1 as compatible with both. Though, you wouldn't be able to use the x-sync chainrings (narrow/wide tooth profile) with a 2x setup and would want rings / crank made for a 2x drivetrain.

Comment: @Benzo And that is why I said potential problem.  You asked "is there any reason".

Comment: Though, sorry to be pedantic, but the XX1 chain works only with the 1x drivetrain, but it seems there is not the same restriction indicated with the X1 chain (made for the lower end 1x drivetrain), It's not listed as having any issue on the compatibility map.  [Compatibility Map PDF](https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/sTuwP23_VJzJytn50DxOK5EgP33HK-ODDtsZRDGHK9Y/mtime:1430932938/sites/default/files/techdocs/gen_0000000004917_rev_c_compatibility_map_2016_mtb_components.pdf)

Comment: Though, sorry I tried to help.  You asked if there is any reason.  Chain compatibility could be a reason.   Based on my input you were able establish SRAM cassette(s) compatible with normal chains.  As you consider other cassettes chain compatibility will again be something you should consider.  You are welcome.

Comment: I don't mean to offend. I appreciate the help. I just thought that you might have meant to say that XX1, not X1 was not designed to be interchangeable after looking at the compatibility chart (which I didn't consider till you brought up this issue and I looked up the chain specs). Sorry about the confusion. I think the points you bring up are definitely good to consider and are helpful.

Comment: I meant the 1X groups as a whole (X1 was a mistake)